# Sending email using SendGrid take long time

Tags: asp.net, email, azure, sendgrid

I using SendGrid in asp.net mvc. I use this code to send email :

```
var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
myMessage.From = new MailAddress("john@example.com");
myMessage.AddTo("testing@something.com");
myMessage.Subject = "Subject";

myMessage.Text = "testing";
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("*********@azure.com", "");
Web transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
```

The problem is that the email take around 5 minutes to reach the destination. Is this the normal case ? if it is normal how can I decrease this time ?

Comment: It depends on the processing speed of the SendGrid and intermediate/destination [Mail Transfer Agent (MTA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) servers. Such latency has nothing to do with the code used as SendGrid will *accept* the message almost instantly on "Deliver".

Comment: Take a look at this [document](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/203884108-Troubleshooting-Delays-and-Latency) on troubleshooting latency with emails. I too have seen issues with SendGrid taking longer than I would want (5 minutes or greater - up to 15 minutes) in my application. I'm just starting to dig into this myself.

Comment: @AhmedShamel have you ever figured out the delay problem with sengrid? I know the . question asked 3 years ago but maybe you still remember somehow? I suspect if it is because of the free account limitation or not.

Comment: @Gunhan In fact, the problem doesn't solved in that time which make me use Gmail (I know it is not a practical solution, but the application was a testing application not a real application). In this time, I am not concern in web applications, thus I don't know If SendGrid has the same problem or not.

Comment: 4 years later and i'm also seeing 5 minute delays with sendgrid when receiving an email on gmail.

Comment: 4 years and 9 months later delays are much more than 5 minutes.

Comment: I seccond that, not sure it it's related to free plan or anything, but sendgrid took more than 30 minutes to deliver the email, some emails are sent faster and some really slow.

Comment: 6 years later. The delays are more than 5 minutes. Some emails sent instantly and some are really slow.

Comment: we have a CICD deploying stuff every morning and we experience delays from 5 minutes to 6 hours literally (luckily we write the actual timestamp in the email).

Comment: 7 years later and it still takes 5 minutes or more to deliver a plain text email. While other providers can do it in seconds...

Comment: 7.5 years later. Still taking ages. Think it's safe to say the service isn't very good at this point! 

Comment: 7.6 years. Is there a better service to use? I looked at mailchimp, but it didn't seem great either.